# Passing a string from C# to cpp with COM

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, string

I have a C# COM server which is consumed by a cpp client.

One of the C# methods returns a string.

In cpp the returned string is represented in Unicode (UTF-16), at least according to the memory view.

1. Is this always the case with COM strings?
2. Is there a way to use UTF-8 instead?
3. I saw some code where strings were passed between cpp and c# as byte arrays. Is there any benefit in this?

Comment: This thread has turned into an unattractive downvoting fest with conflicting answers.  I recommend you look up the definitions for BSTR and SysAllocString in the MSDN Library and draw your own conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.  The standard COM string type is BSTR.  It is a Unicode string encoded in UTF16, just like Windows' native string type.
2. No, a COM method isn't going to understand a UTF8 string, it will turn it into Chinese.  UTF8 is a good encoding for a text file, not for programs manipulating strings in memory.  UTF8 requires anywhere between 1 and 4 bytes to encode a Unicode codepoint.  Very incompatible with basic string manipulations like getting the size or indexing a character.
3. C and C++ programs tend to use 8-bit encodings, compatible with the "char" type.  That's an old practice, dating back from an era before Unicode was around.  There's nothing attractive about it, there are *many* 8-bit encodings.  The typical problem is that data entered as text can only be interpreted correctly if it is read by a program that uses the same 8-bit encoding.  In other words, when the computers are less than 1000 miles apart.  Less in Europe.

Comment: Sounds to me like you've got it backward. He's calling into a C# COM component from C++.

Comment: @sblom: yes, your answer mystified me.  COM looks the same way on both ends.  Automation has always been Unicode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

1. No.
2. Yes. Put [the attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx) `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` before the method definition in C# if you'd like to return the string as an ANSI string instead of Unicode.
3. Yeah--the author may have done that to maintain very fine-grained control on the encoding of the contents of the string by side-stepping the default marshalling behavior.